# Physics body is up above node in SceneKit

Tags: ios, iphone, scenekit, ios11, arkit

I've created a SCNNode object in SceneKit and added a Physics body on it to place in AR world using ARKit. I've tried creating body both from code and from .scn editor from Xcode. However in both the cases, physics body has been placed at different position than node position.

Here is the code for the physics body:

```
    let dimension: CGFloat = 0.15
    let height: CGFloat = 0.3
    let boxBodyShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNBox(width: dimension,
                                                        height: height,
                                                        length: dimension,
                                                        chamferRadius: 0),
                                       options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.boundingBox])
    let boxBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .kinematic, shape: boxBodyShape)


    self.physicsBody = boxBody
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Utilities.CollisionCategoryTree
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Utilities.CollisionCategoryAiko
    self.physicsBody?.mass = 100.0
    self.physicsBody?.friction = 1
    self.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    self.physicsBody?.damping = 1
    self.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
```

This is very simple and traditional code, but it's not working for me when I use SceneKit with ARKit

Here is how it looks when I do in Xcode, when I try to create a box shaped physics body on the object:

[image]

I've also tried with convex shaped body. In case of convex shape, it creates body way above object position. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

The physics body box is half size off from origin. Not sure what's the reason. Has anyone faced this problem?